# Remove the View Report From SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

How can I remove view report button from ssrs report?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the button?

Comment: Maybe with a .net wrapper application.   You can't do it with native SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd okay with the entire parameter bar being hidden (the bar that holds the *View Report* button), access the report via the report server *web service URL* (not the report manager URL) with argument [rc:Parameters=false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms152835.aspx).

If you want the parameter bar displayed just with the *View Report* button removed, it looks like you can do this via JavaScript. @Magnus's article on [how to add a *Clear* button](http://insomniacgeek.com/how-to-add-a-clear-button-to-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs/) should provide a starting place on how to inject JavaScript into the report view page (though your JavaScript will be different as you'll be removing a button instead of adding one).

For complete control over the bars and framing around your report, you can host the [ReportViewer control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405.aspx) in an ASPX page.